# javascript - How to know if page loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I made a script for firefox that navigates through websites. This add-on gets links from the current website to do that, but occasionally my internet goes down (ISP problems) and the page fails to load. Is there any way i could tell this? so i could refresh the webpage until my conection is up again and ff achieves to load the site.

UPDATE:
Example Code:

```
var evt = window._content.document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
var canceled = !window._content.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd need to see some of the code, how are you making the requests to get the other pages?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery

create a div just after a body write some thing

check that value with javascript if the value is same then that page is not loaded properly

`$(document).ready(function() {
  // change the value of that div to conform that page has loaded 
});`